# Why JS cannot find the function in babel script?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Here's my index file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="test">
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fetch-polyfill@0.8.2/fetch.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.js" type='text/babel'></script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        fnc();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here's app.js file

```
function fnc() {
    console.log('myname');
}
```

I wonder why console says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fnc is not defined
    at (index):19
(anonymous) @ (index):19
```

If I change script type with text/javascript, it works without problem.
However, I need it to be babel script for tensorflow script to work in IE11.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69921885/why-cant-i-use-the-function-in-other-js-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In addition to `@CertainPerformance`'s answer,**

If you want to call the function `fnc()` directly, Then the type should be `text/babel`, Because it is defined in `babel` and `transpiled`. If you use `text/javascript` it will search for it in `window` object.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js" type='text/babel'></script>

<script type="text/babel"> //<-- not text/javascript
    fnc(); // works fine
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Babel does is it transpiles code in modern syntax into older syntax. This can be an intensive process - so, it doesn't transpile script tags *immediately*, it'll transpile them asynchronously. The `app.js` has not been transpiled by Babel at the point that the inline script tag runs.

While you could add a delay or add some way to detect when the transpiled script actually runs, a better way to deal with something like this would be to put *all the code* into the script that gets transpiled, so you don't get race conditions like these.

An even better approach would be to transpile the script in advance, and host and load *that* script on your page. Babel Standalone is not a good idea to use in production, because it can be quite heavyweight - better to put the processing effort on your *server*, once, when transpiling, than on every client every time they load the page.

Then you could have something like

```
<script src="/transpiledApp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    fnc();
</script>
```

and it would just work.